# Proof Verification: $(x^n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ diverges when $x>1$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

**Proof**

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $(x^n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to some limit $L$. Consider the identity $(1/x)^n (x^n) = 1$. Since this holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(1/x)^n \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x^n = 1$, and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1/x)^n = 1/L$. But $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1/x)^n = 0$ if $x > 1$, a contradiction. As such, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(x^n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ diverges when $x>1$.

Comment: I am not sure if your professor would accept this. If you can assume that $(\frac  1 x)^{n} \to 0$ you might as well assume that $x^{n} \to \infty$.

Comment: I don't have a professor. I'm self studying. The textbook I'm using specifically states to use the identity $(1/x)^n(x^n) = 1$ and to prove by contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more reasonable argument would be to use the inequaiity $x^{n}=(1+(x-1))^{n} >1+n(x-1) \to \infty$.

Comment: Clever. Thank you.